# $\lim_{p\to\infty}\sum_{n≥1}\arctan\left(\frac{1}{n^p}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Tags: summation, trigonometric-series

I was solving simple series involving the function $\arctan(x)$ of the form :

$$\sum \arctan\left(\frac{d}{ax^2+bx+c}\right)$$

where $a,d,b,c$ are constants. This series can be manipulated too by simple substitutions. The basic idea of solving these types was to convert the original sum to a telescoping series by using the relation (for $x,y>0$):

$$\arctan\left(\frac{x-y}{1+xy}\right)=\arctan(x) -\arctan(y)$$

But , for my curiousity , I tried to see if it's possible to evaluate this for higher degree polynomials instead of quadratics. Using online calculators, I observed that :

$$I_{100}≈0.785$$
$$I_{1000}≈0.78538$$

where
$$I_p=\sum_{n≥1}\arctan\left(\frac{1}{n^p}\right)$$

**Question:**

Can we prove if $$\lim_{p\to\infty}I_p=\frac{\pi}{4}$$ because $$\frac{\pi}{4}≈0.785398$$ which is numerically very close to the sum above ? My knowledge about advanced techniques of calculus to find such sums is very low.

Comment: $\arctan(1/n^p)\to 1/n^p$ for $n>1$ and $p\to\infty$.

Comment: @user Thanks sir. But how can I utilise that ?

Comment: $\lim_{p\to\infty}\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n^p}=0$

Comment: Its just the first term $\text{atan}(1) = \frac{\pi}{4}$. All other arguments go to zero.

Comment: @RolandF Oops ! I see now. It was so simple. Thanks !

Comment: How about monotone convergence theorem?

Comment: It’s worth mentioning that $\frac{x+y}{1-xy}$ creates a natural map from $\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[i]$ so your observation involving sums of arctangents has a related problem of the arctangent of products of complex integers

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal Sorry, I forgot to mention, $x,y>0$.

Comment: Spelt out more concretely if $u,v$ are rational numbers where $u = \frac{a}{b}, v= \frac{c}{d}$ then $\frac{u+v}{1-uv} = \frac{ac-bd}{ad+bc}$ which looks like multiplication of complex numbers

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal I haven't learnt what natural maps are and couldn't understand your first comment. Thanks for showing me that pattern to complex numbers and giving an insight to your first comment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\lim_{p\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\arctan\frac1{n^p}=\arctan{1}+\lim_{p\to\infty}\sum_{n=2}^\infty\arctan\frac1{n^p}=\frac\pi4+0.
$$

The relation
$$
\lim_{p\to\infty}\sum_{n=2}^\infty\arctan\frac1{n^p}=0
$$
follows from summing the inequalities $$0<\arctan\frac1{n^p}<\frac1{n^p}$$
and applying squeeze theorem.